# How can i Create Color simulation with JFrame, JLabel, using setForeground?

Tags: java, swing, animation, colors, jframe

I really doubt this is the best way to do it, but this is what I am working with currently. I have these 3 JLabel objects in a JPanel. So 3 circles are in a JPanel at font 99. left to right the circles are colored R B G.The \u2022 is a circle.

Endgame Goal: Be able to change the circles from on to off. So Say default start is white. I want to be able to do |R W W| or |W B G|. But the problem i am having is, i want the user to be able to see the colors going on and off, that's the whole point. I tried Wait, but it just froze the program and then it yielded the color, without transition. I know it is going to change instantly, but i want to pause it for a few miliseconds, or half a second so the user can see them go on and off.

Example: Second 1 passes, |R W W| second 2 |W W W| second 3 |R B W| Second 4 |W W W| second 5 |R W G|....etc

```
    ballR = new JLabel("\u2022");
    panel.add(ballR);
    ballR.setForeground(Color.RED);
    ballR.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 99));
```

^^ I have one for each color, red, blue, green  ^^

```
    private void colorRed(){

    ballR.setForeground(Color.RED);

    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ballR.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried Wait, but it just froze the program and then it yielded the color, without transition

It is unclear if you are calling this code on the EDT, but from the description sounds to be the case - sleeping (or performing a long running task) on the EDT using will prevent any repaints or listeners from firing until the method returns (in other words, the UI locks up).

> but i want to pause it for a few miliseconds, or half a second so the user can see them go on and off.

If you wish to perform a task on the EDT after a specified time (or repeated time interval), use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

```
Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        ballR.setForeground(Color.WHITE);//or RED, depending
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);//don't repeat if you don't want to
timer.start();
```

Comment: Based on the example provided by the OP, I'm guessing they want to loop 5 times (over 5 seconds), so you should have a repeating timer or `SwingWorker`

Comment: I want to loop over as many as i need to over as long as it takes for the program to finish. so for as long as x, for x number of variables.

Comment: I am a bit confused about the timer. I have a method to change the color back to white at the very end of the code, but it just stays the same color, it wont change to white when its done. IF you can explain a bit in depth i would appreciate it, but im chugging along at it.